# ObjectListView cell contents changing Issue

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

I wanted to pragmatically change the content of a cell. So I have tried something like this

```
Private Structure Items
   Dim ID as Integer
   Dim Name as String
End Structure

Dim objItem as Items 
Private Sub AddItem()
   objItem.ID = 1
   objItem.Name = "Name"
   objectlistview.AddObject(objItem)
End Sub

Private sub ChangeItem()
   objItem.Name = "MyName"
   objectlistview.RefreshObject(objItem)
End Sum
```

AddItem() method is working fine. But ChangeItem() method doesn't work. What's wrong with code

Comment: How are you adding a new row?  It seems like there should be more code here.

Comment: Using a structure type. and used Addobject method to add that object

Comment: I Also tried to update the model object and used RefreshObject method. It also didn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question to include those?  It makes it much easier for us to help you if we can see the relevant code.

Comment: Is your objItem reference in your ChangeItem a part of the objectlistview? As far as I can see your code is fine syntax wise, but if the object itself is not already a part of the objectlistview, I could see why it might just ignore it.